# What is with the rocks in succulent plants?

Tags: plant-care, succulents

I notice that people generally plant succulents in rocks why do they do this? Are my succulents better if I use rocks? What type of rock is best for them?

Answer (score 1):

Mostly what you see is a plant growing in soil, where the soil is topped off with decorative stones that enhance the appearance, artistically but not horticulturally, the plant arrangement. Since the rocks are not contributing to the growing of the plant, the only real criteria are colour, size and a lack of sharp edges. Edges can cut into soft plant tissues leaving brown and black spots and an entry point for pests and diseases. And the appropriate colour really depends on the colour and form of the succulent.

Succulents have a particular pattern of growth; they puff up like a balloon when water and nutrients are plentiful, then they slowly deflate as growth takes place. As they deflate the roots need to breathe air, so they need to drain fast. However they also need to take up nutrients so there has to be some soil to make the nutrients available. To assess whether your soil has dried out you need to see it, but the rocks on top can prevent you from making that assessment unless they are easily removed. Ideally you will be able to tip the pot so that the rocks fall out leaving the soil surface visible for checking dryness. Then wash the rocks and put them back when watering is complete.